Grothdieck differential operators - are they all compositions of first order operators?
Let $A$ be a (unital, commutative, associative) algebra over a field $\mathbb{k}$. Then the ring of Grothendieck differential operators on A is defined as:
$$
\operatorname{Diff}(A) = \bigcup_{\ell \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}} \operatorname{Diff}_{\ell} (A)
$$
where
$$
\operatorname{Diff}_{\ell} (A) = \{\nabla \in \operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{k}}(A) \enspace| \enspace \text{For all } f_{0},f_{1},...f_{\ell} \in A, \enspace \delta_{f_{0}} \circ \, ...  \circ \, \delta_{f_{\ell}}(\nabla)=0 \}
$$
$$
\delta_{f}: \operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{k}}(A) \rightarrow \operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{k}}(A) \\
\delta_{f}(\nabla)(g) = \nabla(fg)-f\nabla(g) ,\qquad f,g\in A,\quad \nabla \in\operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{k}}(A)
$$
$\operatorname{Diff}_{\ell} (A)$ can alternatively be defined inductively. Multiplication is given on the union by composition. Each $\operatorname{Diff}_{\ell} (A)$ is an $A$-bimodule with actions $(f\ast\nabla)(g)=f\nabla(g)$ and $(\nabla \ast f)(g)=\nabla(fg)$. There is a familiar description of the first two modules, namely $\operatorname{Diff}_{0} (A) \cong A$ and $\operatorname{Diff}_{1} (A) \cong A \,\oplus\,\operatorname{Der}(A)$ where $\text{Der}(A)$ are the derivations on A.
My question originates from a comment in an exercise from Nestruev (2020):

In the classical situation $A=C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$, any differential operator of order $>1$ may be represented as the sum of compositions of first-order operators. May one assert the same thing for the algebras [$A=C^{\infty}(\mathbf{K})$ or $A=\mathbb{R}[X]/X^{n}\mathbb{R}[X]$]?

Above, $\mathbf{K}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}\,|\, xy=0\}$ is the coordinate cross in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. For simplicity I have taken the field to be $\mathbb{C}$ below, instead.
The comment seems to imply that there exist operators that are not sums of compositions of first order ones (which I take to mean first or zeroth order). Later parts of the book imply that the existence of such are due to singularities present in the variety corresponding to the algebra. I am trying to write down an example of such, but I am currently dubious to their existence.
I have little experience with analytic things, so take $B=\mathbb{C}[x,y]/\langle xy\rangle$ and $C=\mathbb{C}[x]/x^{3}\mathbb{C}[x]$ as our examples. Some quick calculations of mine show that these have Krull dimension 1 and 0 respectively, and that the local rings $B_{\langle x,y \rangle}$ and $C_{\langle x \rangle}$ have cotangent spaces $ \langle x,y \rangle / \langle x^{2},y^{2} \rangle \cong \mathbb{C}x \oplus \mathbb{C}y$ and $\langle x \rangle / \langle x^{2}\rangle \cong \mathbb{C}x$ which are dimension 2 and 1 over the respective residue fields. So, both of these examples have singular points and thus I would expect there to exist the operators described above. I did this quickly so if I am mistaken please correct me.
Now, to calculate $\operatorname{Diff}_{\ell}$ for $B$ and $C$, I made use of the fact that $\operatorname{Diff}_{\ell}$ is (co)representable (in $B\operatorname{-Mod}$, say) as $$\operatorname{Diff}_{\ell}(B) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_{B}(\frac{B\, \otimes B}{\Delta^{\ell+1}},B), \qquad \Delta=\operatorname{ker}(c \, \otimes \, d \mapsto cd)$$
I calculate that every $\nabla \in \operatorname{Diff}_{2}(B)$ is thus of the form $p(x,y) \mapsto F(1\otimes p(x,y))$ for a $B$-module morphism $F:B\otimes B \rightarrow B$ vanishing on the ideal $\langle (x\otimes 1 -1 \otimes x)^{3}, (y\otimes 1 -1 \otimes y)^{3}, (x\otimes y^{2} - y^{2}\otimes x), (y\otimes x^{2} - x^{2}\otimes y)\rangle$. $C$ is similar except the $C$-module morphism must vanish on $\langle (x\otimes x^{2} - x^{2}\otimes x) \rangle$. One can prove that $\operatorname{Diff}_{1}(B)=\langle 1, x\partial_{x}, y\partial_{y}\rangle$ as a $B$-module. I believe that $\operatorname{Diff}_{1}(C) = \langle 1, \partial_{x} \rangle$ (I may be wrong on this one).
Writing out the relations for these maps on the generators of these algebras gives you pretty quickly the expected second order operators (namely compositions of first order things). But, I can't find any aberrant operators. I would intuitively expect them to already be present at second order, if they exist.
Could anybody provide an example of an operator that is not the sum of compositions of first order operators? Either with these examples or any other.
Thanks

It is perhaps worth noting that for a $\Bbbk$-algebra of finite type, the ring $\operatorname{Diff}$ is a quotient of a Weyl algebra, and so I think the behavior desired in the question is not possible. When your algebra corresponds to a singular variety, the ring $\operatorname{Diff}$ is supposedly poorly behaved/not Noetherian (c.f. Etingof's notes on $\mathcal{D}$-modules). I think this bad behavior is the same thing as the existence of the operators desired in the question.
